# cocos2d screen effect

Tags: iphone, colors, cocos2d-iphone, effect

I am working on my iPhone game using cocos2d. I want to implement the effect: when my hero dies, the screen gradually turns to black/white/grey.  That is, all the UI elements and game sprites' color turn black/white/grey. Could anyone tell me how to do that? I have tried to add a CCColorLayer as a mask, but that doesn't look good. And if you add another image for each elements, the size of the app will double. So any other methods to do this?

Comment: Well i wont suggest the images either. And i think you want to animate the colors form going black to white to grey too(means gradually changing). So a bad way to do it is to create a UIButton of screen size in front(i mean to bring the button in front of the all the elements in your view) and then animate the colors for that button using beginAnimation and commitAnimation. I know its not the best way to do it but that is all i can tell you about COCOs2D

Comment: OK, I will have a try to see if it is the effect I am looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CCTintby ?

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_tint_by.html

It tint's sprites by a colour. You could do it on every child of your gameLayer.

Comment: I have tried that and CCTintTo at the first time. These actions only changed the color property of sprites, not change to grayscale.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can render your scene to a texture and then manually convert the texture's pixels color to gray. Then render the texture to the screen.